# How to chain php if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I am trying to chain a number of if statements using && and it doesnt seem to be working correctly. This is my code.

```
if ($a == "1" && $b >= "10") 
{ echo "1-3"; }
if ($a == "1" && $b <= "9")
{ echo "0-1"; }
if ($a == "2" && $b >= "10") 
{ echo "2-3"; } 
if ($a == "2" && $b <= "9")
{ echo "0-1"; }
if ($a == "3" && $b >= "10") 
{ echo "2-4"; }
if ($a == "3" && $b <= "9")
{ echo "1-2"; }
```

Comment: What do you mean by `doesn't work`?

Comment: Please specify that by **does not work** what do you mean, exactly?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? what doesn't work? also, if $a and $b contain numeric values, try comparing them with numeric values and not strings for example, instead of: `$a == "1" && $b >= "10` try `$a == 1 && $b >= 10`

Comment: What doesn't seem to be working properly? could you provide, actual output and expected output?

Comment: if ((int)$a == (int)"1" && (int)$b >= (int)"10") blind game LOL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare strings, but it won't work the way you think. Comparing strings that way will only compare them based on the characters ASCII codes. (Thanks Rocket)

I assume that you want to compare the values of the numbers, therefore you should remove the quotes surround the numbers.

String: `$b = "1";`
Integer: `$b = 1;` (no quotes)

You might also want to use else if in your if statements here.

Comment: You *can* compare strings.  It compares them based on the characters' ASCII codes.

Comment: Ahh okay. But I assume that's not what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare a String with > or <. Leave out the `"`
(example:

```
if ($a == "1" && $b >= 10) 
{ echo "1-3"; }
```

Comment: Actually, you can.  It compares the strings based on each character's ASCII code.  Which is probably why his comparisons aren't working the way he expects.

Comment: @Rocket, yes that is true, but most likely *not* what the OP desires.

Answer (score 1):

You should take `intval($a)` and `intval($b)` if you are looking for numerical comparison.

You should compare objects in the same domain: `intval($a) === 1` is strict, while `intval($a) == "1"` is typeless. And besides, you **shouldn't** compare a number to a string. As I said, both sides of the comparison should reside within the same domain.

Comment: That won't help.  When you compare a number to a string, it converts both to a string, and then compares them based on the characters' ASCII code.

Comment: You should compare objects in the same domain:
`intval($a) === 1` is strict, while `intval($a) == "1"` is typeless.
And besides, you **shouldn't** compare a number to a string. As I said, both sides of the comparison should reside within the same domain.

Comment: I know that, you should add that to the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is you are comparing a string to an int.  When this occurs, the int is converted to a string, and then the strings are compared based on their characters' [ASCII codes](http://www.asciitable.com/).

You should make sure `$a` and `$b` are ints by using `intval` and then compare them to ints.

```
$a = intval($a);
$b = intval($b);
if ($a == 1 && $b >= 10)
```